# JavaScript non-blocking updates to page

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following code that runs a loop and updates the page as it goes. At the moment the page does not update until the entire loop has run its course.

As you can see, I tried adding a draw function `drawValues` that is called every `5000` times to draw the current values to the screen. My understanding is that when `drawValues` is updated, the page should update and then the main loop will resume with its calculations until another `5000` loops.

At the moment the page will not update until the loop runs in its entirety, somehow ignoring every other call to `drawValues`

**Full Snippet:**

```js
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  var namesAtStart = ["Sam", "John"],
    specialNum = 8,
    amountOfNames = namesAtStart.length,
    counter = [],
    renderCounter = 0,
    x,
    a,
    loopLength,
    number,
    id,
    preId = "content_",
    finalId;

  for (a = 0; a < amountOfNames; a += 1) {
    counter.push(0);
  }

  for (x = 1; x <= specialNum; x += 1) {

    // Start the counter array at zero
    for (a = 0; a < amountOfNames; a += 1) {
      counter[a] = 0;
    }


    loopLength = Math.pow(10, x);
    finalId = preId + loopLength.toString();

    $(".output-small").append('<span id="' + finalId + '"></span>');

    for (a = 0; a < loopLength; a += 1) {
      number = Math.floor((Math.random() * amountOfNames) + 1);
      counter[number - 1] += 1;
      renderCounter += 1;
      if (renderCounter == 5000) {
        drawValues(namesAtStart, counter, finalId, x, a);
      }
      if (a == loopLength - 1) {
        // This is where I am trying to make the code non blocking and async
        drawValues(namesAtStart, counter, finalId, x, a);
      }
    }
  }
});

// This is the part that I want to run when called and update page.
function drawValues(names, counter, finalId, id, currentCount) {
  'use strict';

  var a;
  $("#" + finalId).empty();


  $("#" + finalId).append("<h3>" + Math.pow(10, id).toLocaleString() + "</h1>");

  for (a = 0; a < names.length; a += 1) {
    $("#" + finalId).append(
      names[a] + ": " + counter[a].toLocaleString() + " (" + (counter[a] / currentCount * 100).toFixed(2) + "%)</br>"
    );
  }

  $("#" + finalId).append("Numerical Difference: " + Math.abs(counter[0] - counter[1]) + "</br>");

  $("#" + finalId).append(
    "Percentage Difference: " + Math.abs(
      (counter[0] / currentCount * 100) - (counter[1] / currentCount * 100)
    ).toFixed(6) + "%</br>"
  );

  $("#" + finalId).append("</br>");


}
```

```css
body {} p,
h3 {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.container {} .output {} .output-small {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#stats-listing {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<title>Roll The Dice</title>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="output" id="stats-listing">
      <div class="output-small"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="logic.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Browsers batch updates and afaik don't repaint the page while a script is running, unless it is necessary.

Comment: Any chance you could format/indent your code properly?

Comment: *My understanding is that...the page should update*. Where did you get the understanding that calling a function would update the page?

Comment: @torazaburo, Hmmm, It seems to be formatted in the code snippet editor. I am not sure why some parts are mis-aligning like that. Sorry

Comment: @Joseph: Use spaces, not tabs. The snippet editor has a "Tidy" button, don't know what it does with tabs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main UI thread in browsers, which is used to run JavaScript, is single-threaded. So if you have a function that's taking a lot of time, the browser doesn't update the display.

To give the browser a chance to update the display, you need to yield back to it by letting your current function end and scheduling a timed callback to another run of it for the next block of updates, via `setTimeout`. You'll have to experiment with the browsers you want to support to determine the delay in the timed callback; some browsers are happy with 0 (call back as soon as possible), others want longer (50 — 50 milliseconds — is plenty for every browser I know).

Here's a simple example that adds 10 boxes to the page, yields, then adds another 10, yields, etc. until it's done 1,000 boxes:

```js
(function() {
  var total = 0;
  addBoxes();
  function addBoxes() {
    var n;
    
    for (n = 0; n < 10 && total < 1000; ++n, ++total) {
      box = document.createElement('div');
      box.className = "box";
      document.body.appendChild(box);
    }
    if (total < 1000) {
      setTimeout(addBoxes, 10); // 10ms
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```